# Combining and summing tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am having trouble with an sql query and am looking for some assistance.

I have three tables (table 1, table 2, table 3)

- From table one I have columns a/b
- From table two I have columns c/d
- From table three I have columns e/f

I have combined columns a/c into column g and combined columns d/b into column h

Now I want to match column e to column h (they have the same name) and sum column g grouped by column f. Following that I want to sort it descending.

Here is what I have so far

```
select (one.a + two.c), (one.b + two.d)
from table_1 one, table_2 two
inner join table_3
on (one.b + two.d) = table_3.e
```

I am getting an error "invalid identifier" which I believe is resulting from there not being a combined name for (1.b + 2.d). Does anyone know how to join the two and then sum up column g?

Comment: By "combining", do you mean "adding"?  That is what your SQL does.  If you mean string concatenation, use the `CONCAT` function.

Comment: I am taking one column of length n and another column of length m and turning them into one column with length n+m

Comment: `CONCAT(one.a, two.c)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue may be that you are using an identifier for your tables that begins with a numeric character.  Try having an identifier that begins with an alphanumeric character:

```
select (t1.a + 2.c), (t1.b + 2.d)
from table_1 t1, table_2 t2
inner join table_3
on (t1.b + t2.d) = table_3.e
```

Comment: my table names aren't actually 1,2,3. sorry I changed them before i posted